# Counting Similar Values in SQL With Similar Time Stamps - SQLDF

Tags: r, r-markdown, sqldf

I am looking at ride share data that shows a unique identifier for each rider. I am trying to find if there are riders that may benefit from a membership depending on if they travel the same route on different days of the week and count the quantity. Imagine someone that uses the bike for a daily commute to work, the starting and ending route would be the same. The start and end times would be similar possibly within 15 minutes of each other given circumstances of the commute. The weekdays would probably be more frequent than weekends. And a range of months would show if there is a trend associated with switching commute methods in the warmer or colder months.

```
bikes <- structure(
  list(
    ride_id = c(
      "89E7AA6C29227EFF",
      "0FEFDE2603568365",
      "E6159D746B2DBB91",
      "B32D3199F1C2E75B",
      "83E463F23575F4BF",
      "BDAA7E3494E8D545",
      "A772742351171257",
      "295476889D9B79F8",
      "362087194BA4CC9A",
      "21630F715038CCB0"
    ),
    rideable_type = c(
      "classic_bike",
      "classic_bike",
      "electric_bike",
      "classic_bike",
      "electric_bike",
      "electric_bike",
      "classic_bike",
      "classic_bike",
      "classic_bike",
      "classic_bike"
    ),
    started_at = c(
      "2021-02-12 16:14:56",
      "2021-02-14 17:52:38",
      "2021-02-09 19:10:18",
      "2021-02-02 17:49:41",
      "2021-02-23 15:07:23",
      "2021-02-24 15:43:33",
      "2021-02-01 17:47:42",
      "2021-02-11 18:33:53",
      "2021-02-27 15:13:39",
      "2021-02-20 08:59:42"
    ),
    ended_at = c(
      "2021-02-12 16:21:43",
      "2021-02-14 18:12:09",
      "2021-02-09 19:19:10",
      "2021-02-02 17:54:06",
      "2021-02-23 15:22:37",
      "2021-02-24 15:49:05",
      "2021-02-01 17:48:33",
      "2021-02-11 18:35:09",
      "2021-02-27 15:36:36",
      "2021-02-20 09:17:04"
    ),
    start_station_name = c(
      "Glenwood Ave & Touhy Ave",
      "Glenwood Ave & Touhy Ave",
      "Clark St & Lake St",
      "Wood St & Chicago Ave",
      "State St & 33rd St",
      "Fairbanks St & Superior St",
      "LaSalle Dr & Huron St",
      "Fairbanks St & Superior St",
      "LaSalle Dr & Huron St",
      "LaSalle Dr & Huron St"
    ),
    start_station_id = c(
      "525",
      "525",
      "KA1503000012",
      "637",
      "13216",
      "18003",
      "KP1705001026",
      "18003",
      "KP1705001026",
      "KP1705001026"
    ),
    end_station_name = c(
      "Sheridan Rd & Columbia Ave",
      "Bosworth Ave & Howard St",
      "State St & Randolph St",
      "Honore St & Division St",
      "Emerald Ave & 31st St",
      "LaSalle Dr & Huron St",
      "LaSalle Dr & Huron St",
      "Fairbanks St & Superior St",
      "LaSalle Dr & Huron St",
      "LaSalle Dr & Huron St"
    ),
    end_station_id = c(
      "660",
      "16806",
      "TA1305000029",
      "TA1305000034",
      "TA1309000055",
      "KP1705001026",
      "KP1705001026",
      "18003",
      "KP1705001026",
      "KP1705001026"
    ),
    start_lat = c(
      42.012701,
      42.012701,
      41.8857946666667,
      41.895634,
      41.8347335,
      41.8958076666667,
      41.894877,
      41.895748,
      41.894877,
      41.894877
    ),
    start_lng = c(
      -87.666058,-87.666058,
      -87.6311006666667,
      -87.672069,
      -87.6258275,
      -87.6202531666667,-87.632326,
      -87.620104,
      -87.632326,
      -87.632326
    ),
    end_lat = c(
      42.004583,
      42.019537,
      41.884866,
      41.903119,
      41.8381633333333,
      41.8948858333333,
      41.894877,
      41.895748,
      41.894877,
      41.894877
    ),
    end_lng = c(
      -87.661406,-87.669563,
      -87.6274976666667,
      -87.673935,
      -87.6451235,
      -87.6319791666667,-87.632326,
      -87.620104,
      -87.632326,
      -87.632326
    ),
    member_casual = c(
      "member",
      "casual",
      "member",
      "member",
      "member",
      "casual",
      "casual",
      "member",
      "member",
      "member"
    ),
    travel_time = c(
      6.78333333333333,
      19.5166666666667,
      8.86666666666667,
      4.41666666666667,
      15.2333333333333,
      5.53333333333333,
      0.85,
      1.26666666666667,
      22.95,
      17.3666666666667
    ),
    weekday = c(
      "Friday",
      "Sunday",
      "Tuesday",
      "Tuesday",
      "Tuesday",
      "Wednesday",
      "Monday",
      "Thursday",
      "Saturday",
      "Saturday"
    )
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,-10L),
  class = c("tbl_df",
            "tbl", "data.frame")
)
```

The result would look like

Month | Rideable Type | Start TOD |  End TOD  | Travel Time | W Qty | Days | Total Routes

May | Electric | 12:15 | 12:35 | 00:20 | 3 |  M, W, F | 9

The closest I've gotten is the following but I am almost positive this isn't right although I can't explain why.

```
Select rideable_type, member_casual, start_lat, start_lng, end_lat, end_lng, travel_time, weekday, strftime("%Y", started_at) as "Year", strftime("%m", started_at) as "Month", strftime("%d", started_at) as "Day", count(*) as qty
FROM bikes
GROUP BY start_station_id, end_station_id, travel_time 
HAVING count(*) > 20 
ORDER BY Member_casual DESC
```

The Output is

[image]

Comment: Welcome! To get good help fast, please edit your question to make it [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including sample data

Comment: Hi @jpsmith included some sample data. Let me know if you need anything else. Thank you for your help! As you can probably tell I am new here.